# Transactions don't roll back on IntregrationSpecs with autoFlush

Tags: grails, spock, integration-testing

I'm using Grails. All my Spock Integration tests are working.

But when I turned autoFlush property true, several tests started failing, because data weren't being rolled back.

Any ideas?

*Im using grails 2.1.1

Comment: Maybe something is flushed outside a transaction, or you're using a DDL that is not completely transactional in h2.

Comment: I'm using a custom class to build objects, ie I call myService.buildTeams(), which creates and saves a set of predefined teams. Should I define transactional = false?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem, as long as the method invocation is INSIDE a unit test's transaction.

Comment: I found the problem. It was that one of my test classes was extending from spock.lang.Specification instead of Integrationspec.

Comment: Worth posting an answer. Someone could also run into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my tests was extending Specification instead of IntegrationSpec. When I made it extend IntegrationSpec, all data was rolled back after each test.